# How to add an index to a PDF rendered from an Rmarkdown document using Rstudio on Windows?

Tags: r-markdown

The example document below is intended to include an index after the appendix. In a Sweave document, Rstudio would run a shell escape command to create the index .idx file, but I've not been able to find a way to do this for an Rmarkdown document. Is there a simple header command I'm missing?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
header-includes:
- \usepackage{makeidx}
- \makeindex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# R Markdown

This is an \index{R Markdown} R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

# Appendix - A
End of the document

\printindex
````

I've tried this from both the Knit button and using:

```
rmarkdown::render(rmd.file, output_format = "pdf_document", clean = FALSE)
```

I'm looking for a solution that can run as part of an automated process.

*UPDATE*:
I was able to get the index to work by changing the output type to bookdown::pdf_document2. The additional latex packages were required for a combination of indexing, cross referencing, and formatting.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: no
geometry: margin=0.8in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{attachfile2}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage{makeidx}
- \makeindex
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{setspace}
- \usepackage{relsize}
- \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
- \setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
- \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
- \hypersetup{unicode=true,pdfusetitle,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2,breaklinks=false,backref=false,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue}
---
```

While this would work when manually pushing the create PDF button, the call to `rmarkdown::render()` still does not process the indexing.

Comment: It is weird that it does not work. When you keep the intermediate tex file and compile it outside of RStudio, then the index will be created. What definetly works for me is when you include a template with ` template: myTemplate.tex` in which you include the package and use `\makeindex`